# How to get _id after updating a MongoDB document?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using [.Net MongoDB.Driver 2.2.3](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/) and MongoDB 3.2. I want to get the `_id` of the document I insert or replace with `collection.ReplaceOneAsync()`, because I use it later on.

However the `UpsertedId` of the result is `null` if the operation was an *update* (it is set, if an *insert* happened).

What is the best way to determine the `_id` of the updated document?

```cs
var collection = GetMongoDatabase().GetCollection<BsonDocument>("foos");
var document = new BsonDocument
{
     {"foo", "new bar"}
};
var result = await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(
    Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("foo", "bar"),
    document,
    new UpdateOptions {IsUpsert = true});
// I want to use result.UpsertedId here;
```

If I take a look at `result` after an update in Visual Studio's Immediate Window, I see:

```
?result
{MongoDB.Driver.ReplaceOneResult.Acknowledged}
    [MongoDB.Driver.ReplaceOneResult.Acknowledged]: {MongoDB.Driver.ReplaceOneResult.Acknowledged}
    IsAcknowledged: true
    IsModifiedCountAvailable: true
    MatchedCount: 1
    ModifiedCount: 1
    UpsertedId: null
```

Answer (score 3):

As far I know `ReplaceOneAsync` method doesn't return the `UpsertedId` when the document is replaced, you will see that field with a value when the document is inserted. If you replace an existing document, you can check in your DB that the replacement document is going to have the same `_id` of the old document:

```
var collection = GetMongoDatabase().GetCollection<BsonDocument>("foos");
var d=collection.Find<BsonDocument>(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("foo", "bar")).FirstOrDefault();
var id = d["_id"].ToString();//Check your id here
var document = new BsonDocument
{
     {"foo", "new bar"}
};
var result = await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(
             Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("foo", "bar"),
             document,
             new UpdateOptions {IsUpsert = true});

var d1=collection.Find<BsonDocument>(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("foo", "new bar")).FirstOrDefault();
var id1 = d1["_id"].ToString(); // You will see the same _id
```

Probably the method you are looking for is `FindOneAndReplaceAsync`:

```
var d =collection.FindOneAndReplace<BsonDocument>(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("foo", "new bar"), 
                                                  document,
                                                  new FindOneAndReplaceOptions<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>() 
                                                  { IsUpsert=true,
                                                    ReturnDocument=ReturnDocument.After
                                                  });
var id = d["_id"].ToString();
```